# Почему поле name не переставляется на первое место?

Tags: php, laravel, phpmyadmin

И так я продолжаю постигать прелести работы с Laravel, в этот раз я споткнулся на работе с миграциями, а конкретно на изменении порядка расстановки полей в таблице. Я создал новый миграционный файл следующего содержания:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class ChangeUsers6Table extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table){
            $table->string('name')->first()->change();
            $table->string('sex')->after('id');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Как можно понять из кода, в моей таблице уже был столбец 'name' и ещё не было столбца 'sex'.
По итогу запуска миграций я получил следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А именно, столбец 'sex', как я и хотел встал после 'id', а вот 'name' почему-то не сдвинулся с места. Объясните, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так и как надо делать.

Comment: Если создать новую таблицу а не изменять через change будет ставиться на первое место?

Comment: @DmitriiSedov если я создаю новый столбец и сразу ставлю его на первое место, то всё работает, но переставить уже существующий столбец не получается. В новой таблице, когда я создаю столбцы всё, соответственно тоже работает как надо

Comment: через метод first я имею ввиду

Comment: @DmitriiSedov нет, если я использую метод first при создании таблицы, то получаю синтаксическую. ошибку. Метод работает только при создании новой колонки в существующей таблице.

Comment: значит ответ просто метод change не распространяется на first метод. Попробуйте у name изменить тип и использовать first когда change делаете. Если тип изменится а позиция останется значит я прав

Comment: @DmitriiSedov да, похоже, вы правы, спасибо